# How to refresh only part of page using GAE

Tags: javascript, python, google-app-engine, web

I searched about this concept, but don't really understand how it works exactly. My backend is using webapp2 and GAE, and I want to refresh a page that pulls from my database.

There's other content on the page, and I only need to refresh the table contents specifically. I currently am using

```
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10">
```

to refresh the entire page every 10 seconds, but I need something that only refreshes part of the page. An explanation of any JS or JQuery additions would be great!

The part that I really don't understand is what I have to change on the backend to allow this kind of refreshing.

Comment: All you need from the GAE side is a handler for a URL serving only a JSON of the relevant data.  On the JS script, it's an ajax call, simplest in JQuery.  To get more sophisticated rather than periodic polling you could use Channel, https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/channel/ , a persistent connection which allows the server to initiate sending when changes are detected so the JS doesn't have to poll -- now *that* is cool.  But, better start simple, I guess.

Comment: Sweet! This explanation makes sense. Gonna work on it and get back to you. Thanks for the link about the Channel. Looks really cool.

Comment: Leaving Channel for the future I've sketched a skeletal (but still longish, almost exclusively on the html/js/jquery side of things -- the GAE part is really trivial!-).  So as you can see, "what I have to change on the backend to allow this kind of refreshing" (w/o a Channel, just by polling) is "essentially nothing to all intents and purposes":-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple HTML placeholder:

```
<div id="tablehere"></div>
```

The Jquery code for AJAX-polling every 10 seconds:

```
setInterval(function(){
    $.ajax({ url: "http://yourapp.appspot.com/thetable",
             success: function(data) {
               maketable(data);
             }
          });
}, 10000);
```

JS to make and show a new table (there are a million alternatives here and I'm no JS expert, this is just one way):

```
maketable = function(data) {
  var tabdiv = document.getElementById("tablehere");
  var tabhead = '<table><thead><tr><th>Col1</th><th>Col2</th></tr></thead><tbody>';
  for(var i=0,len=data.length; i<len; i++) {
    tabhead += '<tr><td>' + data[i].col1 + '</td><td>' + data[i].col2 + '</td></tr>';
  }
  tabhead += '</tbody></table>';
  tabdiv.innerHTML = tabhead ;
}
```

and that's it, clientside.

Server-side, `app.yaml` will have a handler

```
url: /thetable
script: thetable.app
```

and in `thetable.py` after all the needed imports:

```
class Tablerow(ndb.Model):
    col1: ndb.StringProperty()
    col2: ndb.StringProperty()

class Tablehandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        data = [tr.to_dict() for tr in Tablerow.query().iter()]
        response.write(json.dumps(data))

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/thetable', Tablehandler)])
```

Phew -- very skeletal but still took me quite a while to write.  But as you can see the app engine part is really trivial -- it's the HTML, Javascript, and Jquery side, that take by far the bulk of the effort!-)

Comment: Thanks! Any problem polling extremely fast (.2 seconds or just putting 0)? I need it to update fast and the app will be used for only 1 hour at a time. I can see the Channel solution as something for the future, but this is a quick solution that I want.

Comment: @tabchas, the more often you poll, the more load you will put both on your server and the users' browsers.  Only experimenting can tell you how much load is too much, depending of course quite crucially on how many browsers are connecting to your GAE app at the same time.

Comment: Understood. Another question: I want a way for users to open this webpage, and whenever they are on that page, it updates the server that they are on the page. It should only work when the user is actually looking at the webpage (not inactive, like from switchings tabs). One way to do this which I have implemented is to keep pinging the server saying that I am alive. Would the Channel API be something useful in this case?

Comment: @tabchas, in how to determine whether the user is looking or not, I'm totally out of my depth -- I'm no full-stack guy, I'm 87% back-end.  I recommend posting a separate Q on this very different issue!-)

Comment: The channel API only works from the server to the browser. To send messages from the browser to the server you will use ordinary GET, POST etc. You can only send messages to the user down the channel, not back up - after all, the tools to send messages back up already exist (i.e. GET, POST).

Comment: You might also want to look at "request-animation-frame" for an easy way to determine if the browser tab is active or not. I believe modern browsers stop drawing when the tab is not in focus - you could leverage that to stop the browser sending the "I'm on the page" messages. There are probably better ways of doing that however.